# Configure local build server to work with a Visual Studio Online account

Tags: build, tfsbuild, azure-devops, checkin

Is it possible to use a local build server for a Visual Studio Online account so that with a gated check-in policy, check-ins are only committed when the build server builds successfully? I don't have expertise in this space, so ideally I'm looking for steps to do the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you are asking.  Simply install TFS Build Server and when you are configuring it give it the URL for your VSO Collection.

Comment: Full walk though: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/15/configuring-a-build-server-against-your-shiny-new-hosted-tfs-account.aspx